Do creatures that are artifacts because of Ygra cause mirrorworks to trigger
If I have both Ygra, Eater of All and Mirrorworks out, would me playing a creature trigger mirrorworks and thus allow me to copy it?

Yes.
Ygra is a static effect that applies to creatures as soon as they are in play, this means that any trigger based on those cards entering the battlefield will see them enter as non-token food artifact creatures, fitting the conditions of Mirrorworks and causing Mirrorworks to trigger.
